# Disable button on filter result

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple issue with ng-disabled on Angular....or I am using it wrong!

Goal: disable a button when a filter returns 1 or more results.

My code:

```
 <button class="ui icon button" type= "submit" ng-model="cars" ng-disabled="     (cars |filter:cars.brand).length)!=0">
```

The problem is that the button is always enabled. Can I use it this way?

Comment: <button class="ui  right floated right labeled icon button" type= "submit" ng-model="frases" ng-disabled="(frases |filter:nueva.palabraClave).length)!=0">

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You are missing one **bracket** try this `(cars |filter:cars.brand).length!=0`. And what object `cars`?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that in principle. You have an extra close-parenthesis in your expression though. It should be: `(cars | filter:cars.brand).length != 0`.

I find that it's sometimes useful to stick a debugging element in your template like this:

```
<div>{{(cars | filter:cars.brand).length) != 0}}</div>
```

This would show you immediately that your expression is not evaluating to anything, and you should also keep an eye on the browser's debugging console, which should contain an error like this in your case:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ')' is an unexpected token
>   at column *xxx*